# How to serialize an array in NestJs

Tags: serialization, nestjs

I am trying to make a serialization but I cannot detect the error that I have,

I am calling an external endpoint and getting this json as a result

```
  sections: [
    {
      availability: [Array],
      address: [Array],
      person_id: '0AC4',
      work_id: '0AC44F',
      title: 'Senior',
      subtitle: 'Full time developer'
    },
    {
      availability: [Array],
      address: [Array],
      person_id: '0AC5',
      work_id: '0AC446',
      title: 'Junior',
      subtitle: 'Mid time developer'
  ],
  schedules: []
}
```

Then I create this class, (just with few elements to test the serialization)

```
export class Person {
    sections!: Section[];

}

export class Section {
    @Expose({ name: 'person_id' }) // Rename property during serialization
    id!: string; 

    @Expose({ name: 'title' })
    title!: string;

    @Expose({ name: 'subtitle' })
    subtitle!: string;

}
```

This is my HTTP call

```
  async findAll(): Promise<Person[]> {
    const apiKey = "";
    const  {info}  = 
    await firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService.get<Person[]>("https://xxxx/api/v2/workers", {
        headers: {
          "api-key": apiKey,
        },
      }).pipe(
        catchError((error: AxiosError) => {
          this.logger.error(error.response?.data);
          throw "Error fetching data!";
        })
      )
    );

    const serializedUser = plainToInstance(Person, info, {excludeExtraneousValues: true});
    console.log(serializedUser[0].title);
    return serializedUser;
  }
```

Controller

```
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  @Get("persons")
  async findPersons(): Promise<Person[]> {
    const workers = await this.server.findAll();
    return workers;

  }
```

When I try to iterate over serializedUsers in my service or get the value of the first element in  the array I am getting that the result is undefined and serializedUsers is a type of object and not a Person[]. I want to have my result from the httpCall in an array of type Person because I want to manipulate the data but I cannot do this